# Computing altitude from contour table - slow ST_Dwithin query

Tags: postgis, postgresql, query, contour, address

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2/PostGIS 2.0. I have a table of house addresses and a table of contour lines which are as follows:

```
address_list

house_id | geom (point, 4283)
---------+---------
    1    | Point
    2    | Point

sa_elevation

   gid   | altitude  |geom (MultiLineString, 4283)
---------+-----------+-----------------
    1    |  100m     | 
    2    |  550m     |
```

I am trying to compute the altitude for each house in the address_list table (approx 6,000 houses) using a 'nearest neighbour' approach ie. find the nearest contour line to the home and tell me what the altitude is for that contour line. My syntax is included below. I use a left join because I don't know if all houses will have a contour line within 3km (following PostGIS in Action p. 137). Note that 3112 is in metres. I've tested the syntax on 5 houses and it works.

But the problem is that if I run it on the whole table and leave it running all night it never seems to finish. I have run vacuum analyse and haves spatial indices on each table. Could someone suggest a faster procedure? Or is there anything else I should do? Many thanks.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(a.house_id) 
    a.house_id, 
    e.altitude AS altitude
FROM address_list AS a
LEFT JOIN sa_elevation AS e 
ON ST_Dwithin (ST_Transform(a.wkb_geometry, 3112),ST_Transform(e.wkb_geometry, 3112), 3000)
ORDER BY a.house_id, ST_Distance(ST_Transform(a.wkb_geometry,3112), ST_Transform(e.wkb_geometry,3112));
```

The explain plan is:

```
   Unique  (cost=232208649.81..232208684.17 rows=6871 width=4109)
  ->  Sort  (cost=232208649.81..232208666.99 rows=6871 width=4109)
        Sort Key: a.house_id, (st_distance(st_transform(a.wkb_geometry, 3112), st_transform(e.wkb_geometry, 3112)))
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..232183921.91 rows=6871 width=4109)
              Join Filter: ((st_transform(a.wkb_geometry, 3112) && st_expand(st_transform(e.wkb_geometry, 3112), 3000::double precision)) AND (st_transform(e.wkb_geometry, 3112) && st_expand(st_transform(a.wkb_geometry, 3112), 3000::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(st_transform(a.wkb_geometry, 3112), st_transform(e.wkb_geometry, 3112), 3000::double precision))
              ->  Seq Scan on address_list a  (cost=0.00..212.71 rows=6871 width=36)
              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..46527.78 rows=42852 width=4073)
                    ->  Seq Scan on sa_elevation e  (cost=0.00..24845.52 rows=42852 width=4073)
```

Comment: We need the `EXPLAIN` plan of the query.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. I have edited the question, is that what you needed? I didn't know the explain plan to be honest.

Comment: Oh, it might be a little slow taken it's comparing every of 6871 houses with each one of 42852 contours. That's some 294 milion comparisons.

Comment: Many thanks Jakub. Of course I should've known you could index on transform. Will check documentation more thoroughly next time.Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need are indexes. You may have indexes on your tables right now but since you're using `ST_TRANSFORM` they're not being used. Indexing on transform is even mentioned on the function's page: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html

```
CREATE INDEX idx_address_3112
  ON address_list
  USING gist
  (ST_Transform(wkb_geometry, 3112))

CREATE INDEX idx_altitude_3112
  ON sa_elevation
  USING gist
  (ST_Transform(wkb_geometry, 3112))
```